# jquery multiple control change by id from name

Tags: jquery, attr

i have this problem, this code work perfectly for the first control of my array of controls  but how to apply it to many item like "product_discount[1 to n][customer_group_id]" without add an "id" attrib?

```
$('select[name="product_discount[0][customer_group_id]"]').change(function() {
    var selected_discount = $('option:selected', this).attr("group_discount");
    $('input[name="product_discount[0][percentage_discount]"]').val(selected_discount);
});
```

thx andrea

Comment: can you share the html

Answer (score 0):

You can combine attribute `^`(starts with) and `$`(endswith) selectors

```
$('select[name^="product_discount"][name$="customer_group_id"]').change(function () {
    var selected_discount = $('option:selected', this).attr("group_discount");
    $('input[name="product_discount[0][percentage_discount]"]').val(selected_discount);
});
```

Comment: hi anoop
it seems not working.. but furtermore i have to pass id [0 to n.] of element to the last row

 $('input[name="product_discount[0][percentage_discount]"]').val(selected_discount);

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="list" id="discount">
                                   <tbody id="discount-row0">
              <tr>
                <td class="left"><select name="product_discount[0][customer_group_id]">
                                                            <option value="1" group_discount="12">Default</option>
                                                                                <option selected="selected" value="2" group_discount="50">prova</option>
                                                          </select></td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" size="2" value="0" name="product_discount[0][quantity]"></td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" size="2" value="0" name="product_discount[0][priority]"></td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" value="3" name="product_discount[0][percentage_discount]"> %</td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" value="0.0000" name="product_discount[0][price]"></td>
                <td class="left"><input type="text" class="date hasDatepicker" value="0000-00-00" name="product_discount[0][date_start]" id="dp1412160209055"></td>
                <td class="left"><input type="text" class="date hasDatepicker" value="0000-00-00" name="product_discount[0][date_end]" id="dp1412160209056"></td>
                <td class="left"><a class="button" onclick="$('#discount-row0').remove();">Rimuovi</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
                                    <tbody id="discount-row1">
              <tr>
                <td class="left"><select name="product_discount[1][customer_group_id]">
                                                            <option selected="selected" value="1" group_discount="12">Default</option>
                                                                                <option value="2" group_discount="50">prova</option>
                                                          </select></td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" size="2" value="0" name="product_discount[1][quantity]"></td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" size="2" value="0" name="product_discount[1][priority]"></td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" value="3" name="product_discount[1][percentage_discount]"> %</td>
                <td class="right"><input type="text" value="0.0000" name="product_discount[1][price]"></td>
                <td class="left"><input type="text" class="date hasDatepicker" value="0000-00-00" name="product_discount[1][date_start]" id="dp1412160209057"></td>
                <td class="left"><input type="text" class="date hasDatepicker" value="0000-00-00" name="product_discount[1][date_end]" id="dp1412160209058"></td>
                <td class="left"><a class="button" onclick="$('#discount-row1').remove();">Rimuovi</a></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
```